# ANTLR - Parsing different line types - mismatched input error

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am using ANTLR for writing grammar for ZOS JCL language.
There can be 4 types of lines:

- Type 1: All statements start with a '//' in the first 2 characters of
  the line
- Type 2: Comments start with a '//*'
- Type 3: lines starting with '/*'
- Type 4: lines starting with any other pattern other than types 1, 2 and 3

Given below is the segment from my grammar file :

```
dd4:    JCLBEGIN ddname  DDWORD '*' inlinerec INLINESTMTEND?;

inlinerec: (INLINEDATA)+ ;
fragment INLINEDATA: (~[\r\n])*;
.
.
.
DDWORD:     'DD';
.
.
JCLBEGIN:       '//'    ;
COMMENTBEGIN:   '//*'   ;
INLINESTMTEND:  '/*'    ;
.
.
WS     : [\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

when using AntlrWorks to run this grammar, the parser rule `inlinerec` is matched correctly but I get the following error:

```
line 24:0 mismatched input 'SORT' expecting INLINEDATA
```

and the section of my code where the error occurs is:

```
//SYSIN    DD  *                                      
SORT FIELDS=COPY
INCLUDE COND
/*
```

How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

> the parser rule inlinerec is matched correctly

It may look that way, but in reality, it is not matched correctly.

> line 24:0 mismatched input 'SORT' expecting INLINEDATA

Fragment rules are not visible in parser rules (therefor `INLINEDATA` cannot be used in `inlinerec`).

Simply removing the `fragment` keyword from `INLINEDATA` will also not work since that rule would greedily match any line. You will need to rethink your approach. I cannot give more specific advise since there is too little to go on. If you have follow-up questions, I suggest you create a new question here on SO with a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem. Good luck!

Also see: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md

Comment: Thanks Bart for your answer. I have created a self contained example for better explaining my problem. Here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592639/antlr-mismatched-input-error